# Are objects accessed indirectly in D?

Tags: object, d

As I've read all objects in D are fully location independent. How this requirement is achieved?

One thing that comes to my mind, is that all references are not pointers to the objects, but to some proxy, so when you move object (in memory) you just update that proxy, not all references used in program.

But this is just my guess. How it is done in D for real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

edit: bottom line up front, no proxy object, objects are referenced directly through regular pointers. /edit

structs aren't allowed to keep a pointer to themselves, so if they get copied, they should continue to just work. This isn't strictly enforced by the language though:

```
struct S {
    S* lol;
    void beBad() {
        lol = &this; // this compiler will allow this....
    }
}

S pain() {
    S s;
    s.beBad();
    return s;
}

void main() {
    S s;
    s = pain();
    assert(s.lol !is &s); // but it will also move the object without notice!
}
```

(EDIT: actually, I guess you could use a postblit to update internal pointers, so it isn't quite without notice. If you're careful enough, you could make it work, but then again, if you're careful enough, you can shoot between your toes without hitting your foot too. EDIT2: Actually no, the compiler/runtime is still allowed to *move* it without even calling the postblit. One example of where this happens is if it copies a stack frame to the heap to make a closure. The struct data is moved to a new address without being informed. So yeah. /edit)

And actually, that assert isn't *guaranteed* to pass, the compiler might choose to call `pain` straight on the local object declared in `main`, so the pointer would work (though I'm not able to force this optimization here for a demo, generally, when you return a struct from a function, it is actually done via a hidden pointer the caller passes - the caller says "put the return value right here" thus avoiding a copy/move in some cases).

But anyway, the point just is that the compiler is free to copy or not to copy a struct at its leisure, so if you do keep the address of this around in it, it may become invalid without notice; keeping that pointer is not a compile error, but it is undefined behavior.

The situation is different with classes. Classes *are* allowed to keep references to `this` internally since a class is (in theory, realized by the garbage collector implementation)) an independent object with an infinite lifetime. While it may be moved (such as be a moving GC (not implemented in D today)), if it is moved, all references to it, internal and external, would also be required to be updated.

So classes can't have the memory pulled out from under them like structs can (unless you the programmer take matters into your own hands and bypass the GC...)

The location independent thing I'm pretty sure is referring only to structs and only to the rule that they can't have pointers to themselves. There's no magic done with references or pointers - they indeed work with memory addresses, no proxy objects.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I give you the context, I am reading A.Alexandrescu, and ability to move object freely means for me, that after move all things are solid as they were. If D uses raw pointers I have no clue how this can be achieved, because after move entire objects is at another address. He writes only about forbidding internal pointers (I see no reason, but this another story). So I can have external pointers.

Comment: What page number is it? I have a copy of the book and wanna check the context. But I'm pretty sure it doesn't really affect external pointers since they are either risky anyway (a pointer to a local variable for example is fine as long as the local remains in scope - afterward, it is all wrong since the var no longer exists), or well defined by the memory allocator (a pointer to a `malloc`'d struct is guaranteed until the object is `free`d', and a pointer to a GC'd object is guaranteed to always be valid.)

Comment: p.249, the second paragraph from bottom. I misused the word `pointer` -- having a `class` you use references to the instances of given type, so `a = new MyClass...` means problem (IMHO) if you would like to move memory occupied by this instance. How `a` will know where the instance lies after the move?

Comment: I'm almost certain that section applies to structs only, but to confirm I asked the D forum: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/dmwzlehrkbrfctdrlgms@forum.dlang.org#post-dmwzlehrkbrfctdrlgms:40forum.dlang.org Though if a class were moved, I'm pretty sure it would be the GC's responsibility to scan all memory for pointers to it and update them too (something it currently can't do, it doesn't know local variable locations that precisely)

Comment: Oh my! You are perfectly right, this entire section deals with `structs` only. So postblit constructor in the first place is `struct` speciality. Now, everything has perfect sense, because it is value type you can reallocate as you wish. Thank you very much for your help Adam!